# Getting Authentication error while accessing Azure Blob tables using Pyspark

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, parquet

We are trying to access Azure tables to fetch data for data analysis activity. But even though we are passing correct SAS token but getting Authentication error as below:

Access Method:

```
import traceback
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.key.jimtestdiag924.blob.core.windows.net', '<SAS Token>')
gps = spark.sql(f"select * from <schema>.<table_name>")
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o145.load.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getFileStatusInternal(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2605)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.util.TablePathUtils.getTablePath(TablePathUtils.java:50)
    at org.apache.hudi.DataSourceUtils.getTablePath(DataSourceUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:84)
    at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:315)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:185)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.exists(CloudBlob.java:1994)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.exists(CloudBlob.java:1981)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.exists(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2087)
    ... 23 more
```

But its working fine if I load parquet file first before executing above query

Parquet file load/Query method:

```
spark.sql("select * from parquet.`wasb://oemdpv3prd-v1@oemdpv3prd.blob.core.windows.net/data/pipelines/<schema_name>/<folder_name>`")
```

Here folder name is same like table name.

Please help me understanding why PySpark-Azure showing such benhavior.

We had metting with Azure support team as well but they also couldn't find any issue from their end.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SAS token, then you need to use spark conf name `fs.azure.sas.<container-name>.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net`, not `fs.azure.key.<container-name>.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net` - if you use `fs.azure.key` you need to provide storage key.